# How to define 'as long as' in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Hi how can I define 'as long as' in prolog?
for example:
sam is the brother of jane as long as they have the same parents?

Comment: `brother(sam,jane):- mother(X,sam), mother(X,jane), father(Y,sam), father(Y,jane).` or something like this. It is quite simple...

Answer (score 0):

"As long as" sounds like a length comparison (if the wrapping paper is as long as the gift) or like a duration (if the concert is as long as the movie).

"Sam and Jane are siblings **if** they have the same parents".

"Mama1 is Sam's mother **and** Mama2 is Jane's mother **and** Mama1 = Mama2".

"MamaX is Sam's mother **and** MamaX is Jane's mother".

Which is @damianodamiano's code

```
mother(X,sam), mother(X,jane)
```

Tests **if** the same person X can fit "mother of sam" and "mother of jane".